# Unable to get AWS Lambda to send message to an SQS Queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Unable to get AWS Lambda to send message to an SQS Queue. I have removed the ids from the queue URL. The code doesn't fail but also doesn't send any message.

```js
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    
    
    exports.handler = async (event) => {
      
      process.env['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = process.env['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_VAL'];
      process.env['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = process.env['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_VAL'];
      process.env['AWS_REGION'] = process.env['AWS_REGION_VAL'];
    
    console.log("11")
    AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-southeast-2'});
    
    // Create an SQS service object
    var sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});
    console.log("22")
    
    var params = {
      MessageBody: "This is a test message",
      QueueUrl: "https://sqs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/11111111111/the-queue-name"
    };
    console.log("33")
    var outcome = await sqs.sendMessage(params, await function(err, data) {
      
      console.log("logging here")
      
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
      } else {
        //Log successful result id
        console.log("Success", data.MessageId);
      }
    });        
  };
```

Comment: Did you check the Cloudwatch logs for the function?

Answer (score 2):

You will need `promise()` at the end of `await sqs.sendMessage` like this:

```js
await sqs.sendMessage(
...
).promise();
```

Ref:
Example index.js file – AWS SDK with async handler and promises
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async